Apt fails to fetch data from reachable IP
I am trying to install some ROS packages on a machine that has several sensors, and is on the very same network than my working computer. While I can install them well on the latter, I am running on this message when I try to do it on the former:
sudo apt install ros-humble-rviz-imu-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ros-humble-rviz-imu-plugin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 409 not upgraded.
Need to get 169 kB of archives.
After this operation, 935 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-humble-rviz-imu-plugin amd64 2.1.3-1jammy.20240126.015719
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-humble-rviz-imu-plugin/ros-humble-rviz-imu-plugin_2.1.3-1jammy.20240126.015719_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap


Both machines are on the same network and I can ping that IP and the ROS packages server just fine from both machines:
ping -c 4 64.50.236.52                                                                                                                                                  
PING 64.50.236.52 (64.50.236.52) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 64.50.236.52: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=144 ms
64 bytes from 64.50.236.52: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=166 ms
64 bytes from 64.50.236.52: icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=142 ms
64 bytes from 64.50.236.52: icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=156 ms

--- 64.50.236.52 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 141.942/151.699/165.653/9.603 ms


ping -c 4 packages.ros.org                                                                                                                                       PING ftp.osuosl.org (64.50.233.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ftp-nyc.osuosl.org (64.50.233.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=133 ms
64 bytes from ftp-nyc.osuosl.org (64.50.233.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=131 ms
64 bytes from ftp-nyc.osuosl.org (64.50.233.100): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=137 ms
64 bytes from ftp-nyc.osuosl.org (64.50.233.100): icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=150 ms

--- ftp.osuosl.org ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 130.888/137.782/149.783/7.286 ms


I have deleted the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.d on the failing machine and copied the contents of the working one, but to no avail.
I have of course tried to sudo apt-get update and sudo apt install ros-humble-rviz-imu-plugin --fix-missing as well.

Even if you can ping the server: the error tells you that any file on that server could not be loaded

Yes, sure. I wasn't saying that I should be able to get it, merely stating that I can see the server and that there is something wrong with the files or my computer, which I can not assess myself.
